# On a Linux host, does FTP to self (from PHP) generate outbound traffic?

Tags: php, linux, ftp, protocols

If I place a PHP script on a host, and in that script FTP a file (local to the script) to a FTP account also ending on that same host, my expectation is that the connection and transfer should be nearly instant as (I hope) no outbound traffic would be generated. But I don't have a way to test this. Is this really the case?

*Update*

1. The FTP host *is not* `localhost`, or `127.0.0.1`. Say we have a
   normal FTP account `johndoe` with a `*******` password on
   `thehost.com`. On this same `thehost.com` we execute our
   `out_of_jail.php` script that will FTP `/css/styles.css` to
   `thehost.com`.
2. This is supposed to work on host environments where
   the admin does not have access to `/etc/hosts` to add `thehost.com`.
3. Let's define `outbound traffic` in the most restrictive way, by it, 
   we mean traffic that goes out to the network card. So, if it goes 
   out and returned as an inbound packet by some other device in the 
   same network, it would still be considered as outbound traffic.

Answer (score 0):

If you point your FTP script to localhost or 127.0.0.1 then there should be no outbound traffic.

If all you're trying to do is get a file from Point A to Point B on the same server via a PHP script, there are other ways to do that besides FTP as well. Of course I do not know all the specifics of your scope or needs, so maybe the FTP approach is right for you. But if you can't get it working, look in to some other options.

Comment: For brevity's sake I left out the _why_. Correct, the reason to use FTP is because of constraints. Are you saying that if we FTP to a non-localhost, we will generate outbound traffic, even if the host resolves to the same machine/ip?

Comment: Well I won't claim to be an expert on this, but I think it will depend on how your machine/network is configured. And, if you are hosting with a company, what constitutes "outbound traffic".

What happens if you run traceroute on the host to the target IP/hostname? If it has multiple hops then you may be hitting outbound. I just tested traceroute to my main IP on a Rackspace box and got 5 hops, meaning it left the server, hit some of Rackspace's network devices, then came back. However, it never left Rackspace's network so it wouldn't be counted as outbound.

Comment: Also, it occurred to me that you could edit the hosts file on the server (i.e. /etc/hosts) to map a hostname to 127.0.0.1, which might be another way to achieve what you need.

Comment: Thank you for the time/effort. I have updated my question to make what is/is not a working solution clear. Unfortunately, adding aliases is not practical in all cases and could not be relied on.

Comment: Did you try running traceroute to the target host and see how many hops it was? I gave bad info before -- I just re-tested on my Rackspace server and got 1 hop pinging to any IP configured on the host.

Comment: Rather than testing on single (or handful of) host(s), I am looking for an answer based on knowledge of the protocols and wide-spread implementations. Something that says based on how FTP is designed and is implemented this will or will not happen. I will do some reading on that to try find an answer.